# css style just works on Firefox (win and mac) - set select option style

Tags: css

I would like to have a select element allowing people to preview the css border-style.

I was thinking with a inline style applied to each option it would be quick and simple to reach my goal, but...

it just work on Firefox, both on Mac and Windows platforms, IE, Chrome, Safari, don't like this.
is there any work-around to make this css cross-browser?

css code

```
.select_border_style {
    border:2px;
    margin:6px;
}
```

html code

```
<select id='borders'>
    <option class='select_border_style' style='border-style:solid;'>solid</option>
    <option class='select_border_style' style='border-style:dashed;'>dashed</option>
    <option class='select_border_style' style='border-style:dotted;'>dotted</option>
    <option class='select_border_style' style='border-style:double;'>double</option>
    <option class='select_border_style' style='border-style:groove;'>groove</option>
    <option class='select_border_style' style='border-style:ridge;'>ridge</option>
    <option class='select_border_style' style='border-style:inset;'>inset</option>
    <option class='select_border_style' style='border-style:outset;'>outset</option>
</select>
```

Thanks in advance

Pluda

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know it can't be done in Chrome. You could, however, use a jQuery plugin to emulate it:

http://jsfiddle.net/GzDXc/1/

I used a slightly modified version of [jqTransform](http://www.dfc-e.com/metiers/multimedia/opensource/jqtransform/)